# Polarion ALM tool

Tags: rtc, alm

we are looking into a full  ALM solution in our company. 
we are looking into Polarion ALM and RTC. 
has anyone ever heard on Polarion complete ALM tool? if so, can you tell me the pros and cons for this tool?
what about RTC? 
i would love to hear your thoughts. 
thanks!
merav

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those tools are both [Application Life Management](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_lifecycle_management) (like you mention in your question), and they both aims at streamlining the development lifecycle.

Currently deploying RTC, I can confirm that the [feature comparison chart listed on Polarion site](http://www.polarion.com/products/alm/index.php) is... disingenuous at best.
From what I can see, all features are present on both products.

For RTC, the "Embedded Version Control Repository" is [Jazz source control](https://jazz.net/projects/rational-team-concert/features/scm).
And RTC is based on a "Based on open standards & frameworks": Open Services for Lifecycle Collaboration (OSLC). See "[Jazz Integration Architecture Overview](https://jazz.net/projects/DevelopmentItem.jsp?href=content/project/plans/jia-overview/index.html)".

The main point regarding RTC is that is an IBM product, meaning choosing that kind of product is often part of a larger set of tools/servers/services linked to IBM for your company.

Comment: thanks... RTC doesn't look that intuitive at all . i would be happy to learn otherwise

Comment: @Mavig: what part don't you find intuitive? I had no major issue introducing it to the developers I am currently assisting.

Comment: it's a lot of clicks in order to do something. in addition, not all screens look the same. in one you need to click on save on the upper right. the other, you need to click on save on the lower part of the screen etc.

Comment: @Mavig: ok. It is still evolving, so I suppose those kind of issues can be entered as an "Enhancement" Work Item in the own RTC project for RTC on jazz.net.

Comment: i guess. do you recommend it as an ALM tool? did you check other tools? (we have linux here also so we need something that will fit all OS's)

Comment: @Mavig: it is a group policy for deploying this tool, after validating said ALM tool on all platform.

Comment: @Mavig: for such large tools, this is mainly a politic decisions, with licenses combined with other software or hardware contracts. The issue for those ALM tools isn't so much in their features, but in the infrastructure behind the tool needed to support said tool: network, database (RTC uses a big Oracle database: you better have your Oracle expert ready), IBM support contacts, ...

Comment: thanks :) we're still investigating though... i hope we will decide really soon :)

Comment: which source control tool are you using?

Comment: @Mavig RTC, as mentioned in my profile on careers: http://careers.stackoverflow.com/vonc