# Pull in RPT Scripts in to RTC by making RPT 8.5.1.3 and RTC 4.0.6 Connection for source control

Tags: rtc, rpt

I am new to RPT/RTC Source control and connection.
I have RPT 8.5.1.3 and RTC 4.0.6 already installed on my client.
After I do right click on my RPT Project --> Team --> Share Project, I am not able to find the connection details i need to input on Share Project prompt window.
I have access to RTC Source control, but I am not sure how to get values to **Host** and **Repository Path** for RPT from RTC.

Can anyone please provide me step-by-step process of connecting RPT to RTC and moving my RPT scripts to RTC Source Control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this resolved.

1. Always start with creating a new Perf Project in RPT - Project Explorer View
2. Create a workspace repository after connecting to Source Control --> Team Artifacts View
3. Pre-condition - Stream and component configured in Source Control. And the flow is set to move from the workspace repository (you created in above step) is set
4. Now share the Project in Proj Explorer View --> Team --> Share
5. Choose the Workspace repository/Folder where you want to move file
6. Now the project is loaded in Workspace repos. Now check-in from --> Pending Changes View
7. Associate the changes to a work item (Optional)
8. Deliver the project from --> Pending Changes View

Answer (score 1):

TLDR; the issue is: the RTC plugin isn't properly installed.
The [OP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3230201/user3230201) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27951941/pull-in-rpt-scripts-in-to-rtc-by-making-rpt-8-5-1-3-and-rtc-4-0-6-connection-for/27952088#comment44344370_27952088):

> The client version of the [**IBM Installation Manager**](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSDV2W/im_family_welcome.html) was lower enough to not update the RTC/RPT Source control (Jazz source control).
>   Hence updating Instal manager and then modifying the Jazz source control resolved this.

---

Original answer (for illustrating the symptoms)

From what I can see of the white paper "[Integrate Rational Team Concert and Rational Performance Tester for collaborative script development, version control, and process management](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/09/integraterationalteamconcertandrationalperformancetester/)", you don't need to enter an Host and repo path "for RTP" (RTP being the "[IBM Rational Performance Tester](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/downloads/r/rpt/)").

The only step where you need to enter that kind of data is strictly for RTC (RTC being the "[IBM Rational Team Concert](http://www-03.ibm.com/software/products/en/rtc)", an [ALM tool](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8490883/6309)):

[image: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/09/integraterationalteamconcertandrationalperformancetester/image006.jpg]

If you see any other "connection" windows on the "Share project" step, that means you selected the wrong Version Control tool on that step.
So if you see one for CVS:

[image: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/ajax/download?nodeId=af0215fc-731f-4290-8401-1da0f6a287ed]

That just means you didn't click the right line (which should be "Jazz source Control"):

[image: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/09/integraterationalteamconcertandrationalperformancetester/image010.jpg]

Comment: Hi Von Appreciate your answer. Should I try uninstalling RTC and re-installing? Bcoz I dont see the last screen shot you attached, as I am stuck at Host/Repository path prompt window only

Comment: @user3230201 do you mean you don't see the Jazz Source Control option? If so, then yes, uninstall/reinstall RTC should do the trick.

Comment: Yes. Right after RPT Project --> Team --> Share Project, I see Enter Repository location Prompt which has Host/Repo path/Authentication/Connection type etc fields

Comment: And now i think, its something related with RPT that needs to be changed. May be to include Java Source Control Plug-in. Where that is to be doe in RPT is another big question. :(

Comment: Found the solution - the client version of the IBM Install Manager was lower enough to not update the RTC/RPT Source control(Jazz source control). Hence updating Instal manager and then modifying the Jazz source control resolved this. Thanks for the help

Comment: @user3230201 Excellent: I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.